# How to send email with schedule queue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, cron, schedule

I would like to send email using artisan command on laravel project

So I have created command and tried to send email using artisan command.

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Console;
    
    use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
    
    class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
    {
        /**
         * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $commands = [
            Commands\DailyQuote::class,
        ];
    
        /**
         * Define the application's command schedule.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
         * @return void
         */
        protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
        {
            $schedule->command('quote:daily')
                ->everyMinute();;
        }
    
        /**
         * Register the commands for the application.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        protected function commands()
        {
            $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');
    
            require base_path('routes/console.php');
        }
    }
```

I have made app/console/kernal.php like above.

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

use App\Mail\InvoiceNotification;

use Mail;

class DailyQuote extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'quote:daily';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Send notification to user who will expire';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {

        $details = [
            'lastname' => '$client->lastname',
            'invoiceUrl' => 'https://billing.hutv.me/invoice_view/invoice_id',
            'invoiceDueDate' => '$client->expiration'
        ];
        Mail::to('receiver@mail.com')->send(new InvoiceNotification($details));
        
        $this->info('Successfully sent daily quote to everyone.');
    }
}
```

And this is my `app/console/commands/DailyQuote.php`

I have executed with `php artisan quote:daily` command on the Ubuntu server

But Email is not sending with no error.

So I have tried to call command on my other controller

```
Artisan::call('quote:daily');
```

It is working and sending email.

I don't know what is the problem for that issue.

If somebody has good solution, please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: When it worked with the command was it on your local machine or in the server? Make sure you have the right credentials set in the environment variables of your server.
By the way, in your `$details` array, do not surround variables with simple quotes because you'll get that string literally. Instead, just remove the `'`.

Comment: It works to send email with controller on Server

Answer (score 0):

make laravel Notification by `php artisan make:notification InvoiceNotification` and this should implements ShouldQueue like:

```php
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use App\Mail\BaseMail; // optionaly your email template

class InvoiceNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new BaseMail())
                    ->subject('your subject')
                    ->to($notifiable->email);
    }
    // ...
}
```

and then send e.g. by

```
    public function handle()
    {

        $details = [
            'lastname' => '$client->lastname',
            'invoiceUrl' => 'https://billing.hutv.me/invoice_view/invoice_id',
            'invoiceDueDate' => '$client->expiration'
        ];
 
        Notification::route('mail', 'receiver@mail.com')
                                    ->notify(new InvoiceNotification($details))
        $this->info('Successfully sent daily quote to everyone.');
    }
```

Comment: why do you think my code is not working? I think it is not a problem to implement queue and Notification or Mailable. Can you show me an example code you built like this?